# Using output of head -1

Tags: bash, pipe, head, ls, io-redirection

When I write

`ls | head -1`

the output is

> file.txt

When I write

`ls | head -1 > output.txt` or

> echo `ls | head -1` > output.txt

the file output.txt contains

> ^[[H^[[2Jfile.txt

This makes me trouble because I need to use the output of `head -1` as an argument of another command.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly your `ls` is aliased to something like `ls --color=always`. Try `/bin/ls | head -1 > output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

These are probably terminal escape codes for coloring. Your `ls` setup seems to be broken, normally coloring should only be done when connected directly to a terminal.

```
ls --color=never | head -1
```

should fix the issue.